# How to start a class before Spring has initialized?

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to execute a class before the Spring container has been initialized?

Basically, I have some resources which I have scattered across the jars that make up my application. Upon first the very first execution of the application, they won't be on the file system and people will need to be able to adjust these configuration files sometimes. So... instead of editing them and re-packaging, I would like to be able to copy all these resources outside the respective jars into an extracted directory structure where they could easily be changed. I have so far implemented this. However, I now need to be able to actually do this before Spring's container has been initialized so that they are present when Spring tries to initialize. How can this be done?

I would need to be able to do this both from a webapp perspective and in a JUnit test.

Comment: depends on how you initialize spring context ?

Comment: use a servlet context listener

Comment: Is this in the context of a Servlet based web application?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It is, but I will also need to be able to do it in a JUnit test.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Do you know of a way to do it for the case where I need it to be in the container used for testing (JUnit)...?

Comment: Are you using `MockMvc`? I believe you can register listeners there too. Otherwise use the `@Before` and `@After`, and other relevant Junit processes.

Comment: No, I'm not using `MockMvc`. Is `@Before` executed before the Spring container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a ServletContextListener:add the following to your web.xml before spring servelt.

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>your.full.className.YourListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

where YourListener looks like:

```
public class YourListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent evt) {
         //execute anything here.
    }
}
```

Comment: What if it isn't a web application?